# Returning key values from an array of object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I am 99% there with the code below but I need this array of objects to return:-
'Bear', 'Minu', 'Basil', 'Hamish' instead it returns Bear,MinuBasil,Hamish any ideas?

```
    gatherPets([{ name: 'Malcolm', pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'] },{ name: 'Caroline', pets: ['Basil', 
    'Hamish'] },]);

    function gatherPets(people) {
      let newArray=[];
      for (let i=0; i <=people.length; i++ ) {
        newArray = newArray +people[i].pets
      }
      return (newArray)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this code helping you

```
array.flatMap(o=>o.pets)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method for this.

```js
export function gatherPets(pople){
  return people.flatMap(p => p.pets);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic I love how efficient this is. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
gatherPets([{ name: 'Malcolm', pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'] },{ name: 'Caroline', pets: ['Basil', 
'Hamish'] },]);

function gatherPets(people) {
let newArray=[];
for (let i=0; i <people.length; i++ ){
newArray.push(...people[i].pets);    
}
return (newArray)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Maharajan thats perfect, I tried a push this way but it did not work when I tried it because I did not precede the people[i].pets with the ... What do the ... stand for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push()` to push the values in the new array and `flat()` to flatten it.

```js
function gatherPets(people) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(people[i].pets);
  }
  return newArray.flat();
}

const people = [{
  name: 'Malcolm',
  pets: ['Bear', 'Minu']
}, {
  name: 'Caroline',
  pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish']
}, ];

const result = gatherPets(people);
console.log(result);
```

Or you could simply use `flatMap()`

```js
const people = [{
  name: 'Malcolm',
  pets: ['Bear', 'Minu']
}, {
  name: 'Caroline',
  pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish']
}, ];

const result = people.flatMap((p) => p.pets);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you the flatMap() method is super useful.